# Can we access prayer room during transfer in Suvarnabhumi Airport (BKK)?

Tags: airports, religion, bkk

I checked for a prayer room in Suvarnabhumi Airport (BKK).

Is it accessible during transfer?

Answer (score 7):

There is a [prayer room](http://suvarnabhumiairport.com/en/50-prayer-room) available in the international part of the airport. Based on the [map](http://suvarnabhumiairport.com/en/124-within-the-terminal), it appears to only be accessible to travelers awaiting any international departure. International arrivals and domestic arrivals/departures do not have access to this area unless you are connecting to an international departure.

There is also apparently a second prayer room, not indicated on the airport website or map, in the domestic departures area. This [Muslim-friendly guide to Suvarnabhumi Airport](https://www.halaltrip.com/airport-details/11/bangkok-suvarnabhumi-international/) has details, along with some other helpful information about the airport.

I have confirmed this with the helpful "live chat" feature BKK is kind enough to provide on their website. They inform me that: "1. It's on the 2nd fl. near Concourse C. and 2. on the 3rd fl. near Concourse E."

Comment: https://papayapokpok.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/suvarnabhumi-muslim-prayer-room/ says there's one in domestic departure too

Comment: @Berwyn Nice find. It's not on their website. I'll incorporate it into the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Also here from 2015 https://www.halaltrip.com/other/blog/thailands-best-airports-for-muslim-travelers/

Comment: https://www.halaltrip.com/airport-details/11/bangkok-suvarnabhumi-international/ says there's another one landside too. Spoilt for choice!